# Dropbox copy file to another account not working in C# using Dropbox.NET SDK API v2

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to copy a file from a dropbox account to another account. I'm trying the below code-

```
var client = new DropboxClient("c4zvSWqce");
await client.Files.CopyReferenceSaveAsync(strCopyRef, Path);
```

The CopyReference value is looking correctly but calling CopyReferenceSaveAsync showing error "no_permission". Please see the attachment. I couldn't find the reason for this error.
Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is there a question hidden?

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox API forum: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206156683-Dropbox-copy-file-to-another-account-not-working-in-C-using-Dropbox-NET-SDK-API-v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-copy_reference-save) gives the following definition for that error:

> `no_permission` Void You don't have permission to save the given copy reference. Please make sure this app is same app which created the copy reference and the source user is still linked to the app.

Perhaps the access tokens you're using (for source and destination) are not for the same app?